# SQL an opening bracket was expected

Tags: sql

Can anyone please look over my code, I keep getting the following errors

1. An opening bracket was expected. (near "AS" at position 43)
2. At least one column definition was expected. (near " " at position 42)
3. Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 695)

However, I did use the opening bracket and close it at the end. I can not see any syntax error with Atom

```
CREATE TABLE marketin_testDatabase.results AS (
    SELECT
        /*begin of the variable list for log_link_visit_action*/
          llva.`idlink_va`,
          llva.`idsite`,
          llva.`idvisitor`,
          llva.`idvisit`,
        /*end of the variable list for log_link_visit_action*/
        /*begin of the variable list for log_visit*/
          -- lv.`idvisit`, -- duplicate column name
          lv.`idsite`,
          lv.`idvisitor`,
          lv.`last_idlink_va` -- remember to delete the last comma
        /*end of the variable list for log_visit*/
        FROM marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_link_visit_action llva -- create alias for the long table name
        LEFT OUTER JOIN marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_visit lv
    ON lv.idvisit =
    llva.idvisit
);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: That is valid standard SQL (although the parentheses around the select are useless). I assume your database product simply doesn't support that - given the presence of the dreaded backticks I assume that you use MySQL and that does indeed not support this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `CREATE TABLE` syntax, you need to specify all columns and data types in parenthesis, that's why an opening bracket is expected. You can use `SELECT INTO` statement:

```
SELECT
      llva.`idlink_va`,
      llva.`idsite`,
      llva.`idvisitor`,
      llva.`idvisit`,
      -- lv.`idvisit`,
      lv.`idsite`,
      lv.`idvisitor`,
      lv.`last_idlink_va`
INTO marketin_testDatabase.results
FROM marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_link_visit_action llva 
LEFT OUTER JOIN marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_visit lv
ON lv.idvisit = llva.idvisit
```

Does the table `marketin_testDatabase.results` already exist? If yes, do you want to add to it or rewrite it?